# Show Image in Chrome extension popup

Tags: java, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to reach a point where my extension can show not only a notification that a website is updated, but also a small image that represents this update from that site. The only way I seem to get this to work is if the user has the updated page in a tab. In this case, I just reference the document.ImageSrc

> img[i] = document.images[i].src;

or iFrame and it will show the first image of that page.
The problemis that  an update extension that forces the user to click on the page is useless; download an extension to show updates of a page they'd have to open anyway.
Is there a way around this?
A way to show a preview of the page without being on it? Or to display the first image of a page? Or first tweet without being on twitter?

Other question wasn't answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show preview of updated page in Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720446/show-preview-of-updated-page-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Don't ask twice the same question on stackoverflow, see [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). And in a 10 hour span? lol. As the help link suggests, improve your original question as it's vague now.